# How to override the validation rule login Laravel\Fortify?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

This described in the class Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest
I want to add one more validation line

```
namespace Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
/..
    public function rules()
        {
            return [
                Fortify::username() => 'required|string',
                'password' => 'required|string',
            ];
        }
}
```

But I cannot do the customizations in the vendor.
My question is how to do this?

Comment: @JanosAudran has given you the correct answer. It is the correct way to achieve what you intend to do. As Snapey and TheSk8rJesus have pointed out, it is a bad practice to make changes to the vendor folder. You might get the job done by making changes to the vendor folder but it is a bad practice to say the least. Try what JanosAudran has suggested.

Answer (score 15):

Just to add to the comment above, it's a bad idea to make changes in the vendor folder as stated earlier. For one, any code pushes to a repository will not reflect these changes (unless you modify the ignore file).

For Laravel/Fortify adding new fields and changing the default validation rules, even the password requirements is very straightforward. It's not clear to me what your requirement is, but it might be easier to simply use a Validator. That is what Fortify uses as well. For example, Fortify publishes two files:

```
App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser.php
App\Actions\Fortify\PasswordValidationRules.php
```

To add a new validation rule for a field, simply add it the CreateNewUser.php under the Validator::make method that Fortify itself is using. You can follow the same logic in your custom implementation. For example to add a firstname field, modify as follows:

```
Validator::make($input, [
            'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        ])->validate();

        return User::create([
            'firstname' => $input['firstname'],
        ]);
```

You can add as many field as you want. To change the password requirements, make changes to the passwordRules() function in the PasswordValidationRules.php file as follows:

```
protected function passwordRules()
        {
        return ['required', 
        'string', 
        (new Password)->requireUppercase()
        ->length(10)
        ->requireNumeric()
        ->requireSpecialCharacter(), 
        'confirmed'];
    }
```

All this info can be found at the official docs https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/features/authentication.html#password-validation-rules

Comment: For some reason, that didn't worked for me. I tried to put a length of 3 characters and take out the confirmation, but it doesn't work, keep wiating for 8 characters and with confirmation

Comment: My question was about the login, everything is clear with the password and registration.

Comment: I like to set up a conditional statement on my password complexity file.  `if (App::environment('local')) { /* simple rules */ } else { /* complex rules */ }`.  It helps with testing in a development environment.

Answer (score 10):

Here's how you can use your own validation rules when authenticating with Fortify:

1. Create a file `LoginRequest.php` in App\Http\Requests that extends Fortify's `LoginRequest.php` class

> I would just copy that class and update the namespace:

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest as FortifyLoginRequest;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

class LoginRequest extends FortifyLoginRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            Fortify::username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'myAttribute' => 'rules' // Customizations... 
        ];
    }
}
```

2. Add a binding in your `AppServiceProviders.php` boot method to resolve Fortify's class with your own:

```php
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->bind('Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest', \App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest::class);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but shouldn't this be $this->app->singleton('Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest', \App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest::class); instead of app->bind?

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. @Rhdr I don't know the difference between `app->bind` and `->app->singleton` but the first one works for me

Answer (score 3):

In short, I solved the problem like this

copy vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Http\Controllers\AuthenticatedSessionController.php to
app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php (change namespace and class name)
copy vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Http\Requests\LoginRequest.php to app\Http\Requests\LoginFormRequest.php (change namespace and class name)

add new route in routes/web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
//
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'store'])
        ->middleware(array_filter([
            'guest',
            $limiter ? 'throttle:'.$limiter : null,
        ]));
```

in LoginController changed LoginRequest to LoginFormRequest and

```
public function store(LoginFormRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->loginPipeline($request)->then(function ($request) {
            return app(LoginResponse::class);
        });
    }
```

in  LoginFormRequest add my new rule(s)

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            Fortify::username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'myNewRule' => 'required|string',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Editing the vendor folder is not ideal. Instead, you can use the `Fortify::authenticateUsing()` method in Fortify to validate incoming authentication credentials in your Laravel app. All you need to do is add the method in the `FortifyServiceProvider.php` boot method:

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
    Validator::make($request->all(), [
       Fortify::username() => 'required|string',
       'password' => 'required|string',
       'myAttribute' => 'rules'
    ])->validate();

    // Find User
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if ($user &&
      Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
      return $user;
    }
});
```

Don't forgot to import the validator class.

Answer (score -3):

I've found that page: https://dev.to/aibnuhibban/login-customization-in-laravel-8-2gc8

Go to vendor > laravel > fortify > src > Rule > Password.php

There you can change those config.

Comment: However Jetstream's documentation provides an example:<br/>
[Password Validation Rules](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/features/security.html#password-validation-rules)
<br/>
`(new Password)->length(10)<br/>
<br/>
// Require at least one uppercase character...<br/>
(new Password)->requireUppercase()<br/>
 <br/>
// Require at least one numeric character...<br/>
(new Password)->requireNumeric()`<br/>
<br/>
But that is very unclear for me how to use them, where to put them..

Comment: I need change login validation, add new field. Everything is clear with the password

Comment: You really shouldn't be making changes in the Vendor folder. Any changes made in your vendor folder will be local only. If cloned by another user they will not receive your changes.

Comment: never, ever edit code in the vendor folder.  It will be overwritten whenever you redeploy your application or update packages